# How to call a mongoose schema methods inside a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use a custom schema methods inside my controller...

```js
schema.methods.assignRole = function (role: string | IRole) {
    if (instanceOfIRole(role)) {
            this.role = role;
    } else {
        this.role.name = role;
    }

    this.role = role;

    return this.save();
};
```

inside a route "/user/toAdmin": (this is not the definitive function just a "blueprint")

```js
router.get("/user/toAdmin", async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    const user = await Users.findOne({ username: "administrator" });

    const role = {
        name: "admin",
        permissions: [
            {
                name: "view-user",
            },
            {
                name: "create-user",
            },
            {
                name: "edit-user",
            },
            {
                name: "delete-user",
            },
        ],
    };

    // ????
});
```

I've tried:

```js
user.assignRole(role);
```

And got this error:

```
Property 'assignRole' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & Omit<IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>'.ts(2339)
```

sorry for my disastrous english I'm french :/

Comment: Please add your schema and model definitions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've update my IRole interface to :

```js
export interface IRole {
    name: string;
    permissions: { name: string }[];
}

export const instanceOfIRole = (object: any) => {
    if (!(object instanceof Object)) return false;

    return "name" in object;
};
```

and my IUser interface to :

```js
export interface IUser extends Document {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    profile?: {
        firstname?: string;
        lastname?: string;

        avatar?: string;
        bio?: string;
    };
    active: boolean;

    assignRole(role: string | IRole): Promise<IUser>;
}
```

And finaly my route to:

```
router.get("/toAdmin", async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    const user = await Users.findOne({ username: "administrator" });

    const role: IRole = {
        name: "admin",
        permissions: [
            {
                name: "view-user",
            },
            {
                name: "create-user",
            },
            {
                name: "edit-user",
            },
            {
                name: "delete-user",
            },
        ],
    };

    await user.assignRole(role);
});
```

if for some reason you want the code it's [here](https://github.com/open-webradio/open-webradio)

:D